# Omnivorous video player for iPad

Tags: video, ios, media-player, ipad-app

I need video player software which can play any video format from Samba share.

Many players I tested sometimes were unable to play sound. During that players were not reporting any error. So I won't believe vendor declarations that their player will able to play - I need to see it myself before pay. So any players incapable to show its powers are unacceptable (like Infuse or PlayerXtreme).

Answer (score 2):

## VLC

[image]

[VLC for iOS](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ios.html) is a new edition of the venerable cross-platform video-playing software. Famous for playing a wide variety of video formats.